# AngularJs 1.5 :How to reload a current route/component on some event?

Tags: angularjs, angular-routing, angularjs-components

i am using `Angularjs-1.5` with `typescript` and `components`.
I have 2 goals to achieve:

**1.**   I have a scenario where in i need to recall a life-cycle of my current `controller/component` i.e. its `constructor()`,`$onInit()` etc.etc.

For that i have tried multiple things but nothing worked as i expected:

```
constructor(){
     let self=this;
    this.$rootScope.$on("myEventName",function(){

            // self.$rootRouter.reload();//does nothing.
           // $window.location.reload();//refresh browser page,so wont be useful.


        });
}
```

**2.** in one of my child component router does not work for one specific scenario whereas it works for other scenarios :

```
this.$rootRouter.navigate(['Customers', 'CustomerDetails']);
```

ideally this route should navigate me to customer details page, but it does do nothing,even any console error is also not displayed.Same code works in one other scenario.

Can anyone guide me to achieve this. Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use `$state.reload()`;
2. Try with `$state.go('CustomerDetails')`

Comment: Aren't you able to inject it on the controller whose the function `constructor()` belongs?